# Dielectric constant of conductors

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, dielectric

Good conductors have [infinite dielectric constant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238111/what-is-the-dielectric-constant-of-a-pure-conductor). That means their [skin depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect#Formula) is also infinite ( or very large). This means they are very poor at blocking electromagnetic waves, which is a contradiction. What am I missing?

Comment: the wikipedia page does not talk about dielectric constant. could you please elaborate how it addresses the contradiction highlighted here?

Comment: Notice that in the Q&A you linked, the argument for an ideal conductor having infinite dielectric constant follows from the fact there's no electric field within an ideal conductor.  This is because the conductivity of the ideal conductor is also infinite. The infinite conductivity (and so zero E field) also implies skin depth is 0, not infinite.

Comment: @JackI "metal is transparent"! that is the contradiction. metals are used for shielding against electromagnetic waves. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding#Materials_used

Comment: @ThePhoton  so to resolve this matter we need to know the relationship between conductivity and permittivity. is this what you are saying?